# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subscribe') in Jasmine

Tags: jasmine, karma-runner

I am trying to write the test cases for the below method :-

```
 subscriptionPackages() {
    this.managePackageService.getPackages().subscribe(
      (response) => {
        this.packagePlan = response;
      },
      (httpErrorRes) => {
      }
    );
  }
```

I have tried the below snippet in my spec.ts file for covering the above code :-

```
  fdescribe('AddProductComponent', () => {
  let component: AddProductComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AddProductComponent>;
  let packageServiceStub = jasmine.createSpyObj('ManagePackageService', ['getPackages']);

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule,ReactiveFormsModule,FormsModule,ToastrModule.forRoot(),
        TranslateModule.forRoot(), NgSelectModule],
      declarations: [ AddProductComponent ],
      providers :[AppConfig,
        { provide: ManagePackageService, useValue: packageServiceStub }]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AddProductComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.packagePlan = [{'name':'basic', 'id':1}, {'name':'advance', 'id':2}, {'name':'premium', 'id':3}];
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

it('should create  subscriptionPackages', () => {
  const mockpackageResponse = []; 
  packageServiceStub.getPackages.and.returnValue(of(mockpackageResponse));
  component.subscriptionPackages();
  expect(component.packagePlan).toBeTruthy();
 });
```

From this code my test case is covered but I am getting below error :-

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you call `subscriptionPackages` in the `ngOnInit` or the `constructor` of the component?

If you're calling it in the `ngOnInit`, you need to mock the `returnValue` before the first `fixture.detectChanges()`. The first `fixture.detectChanges()` is when `ngOnInit` is called.

```js
beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AddProductComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    // !! Move this line here if calling subscriptionPackages in ngOnInit !!
    packageServiceStub.getPackages.and.returnValue(of(mockpackageResponse));
    component.packagePlan = [{'name':'basic', 'id':1}, {'name':'advance', 'id':2}, {'name':'premium', 'id':3}];
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

it('should create  subscriptionPackages', () => {
  const mockpackageResponse = []; 
  component.subscriptionPackages();
  expect(component.packagePlan).toBeTruthy();
 });
```

```js
beforeEach(() => {
     // !! Move this line here if calling subscriptionPackages in constructor !!
    packageServiceStub.getPackages.and.returnValue(of(mockpackageResponse));
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AddProductComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.packagePlan = [{'name':'basic', 'id':1}, {'name':'advance', 'id':2}, {'name':'premium', 'id':3}];
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

it('should create  subscriptionPackages', () => {
  const mockpackageResponse = []; 
  component.subscriptionPackages();
  expect(component.packagePlan).toBeTruthy();
 });
```

Comment: Thanks it is resolved now.

Comment: is this also working in the case if we invoke method inside `ngOnChanges`, just like I did for 'subscriptionPackage()', What if the same method `ngOnChange`.

Comment: `ngOnChanges` only runs if an `@Input` property changes from the parent component. You can call `ngOnChanges` manually though if you don't want to host your component in parent component. Check out this post: https://medium.com/@christophkrautz/testing-ngonchanges-in-angular-components-bbb3b4650ee8.

Comment: I have just post this post, please check the below link, If you have any idea of this kindly suggest me the solution. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70000998/typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-value

Comment: I found that any subscribe is better done on the OnChange event and keep the ngOnInit as simple as possible solves this problem - thanks