# Call created spy before change detection

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-test

I want to call created spy method before change detection is triggered. here is my mocked class.

```
const stubStudentService: Pick<StudentsCrudService, keyof StudentsCrudService> =
  {
    getAllStudents: jasmine
      .createSpy('getAllStudents')
      .and.returnValue(of(studentPayload)),
     ...other methods
  };
```

How do I call that `getAllStudents` before `fixture.detectChanges()`

```
 beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(StudentsListComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    <-- want to call that spy here --->
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

I wanted to do this because of this issue. but can't figure out how to change the solution according to my mocked service [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69989284/...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69989284/typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-subscribe-in-jasmine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `TestBed.inject` here:

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    // ...
    providers: [
      {
        provide: StudentsCrudService,
        useValue: stubStudentService,
      },
    ],
  });
});

beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(StudentsListComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;

  const studentsCrudService = TestBed.inject(StudentsCrudService);
  // spyOn(studentsCrudService, 'getAllStudents')...;

  fixture.detectChanges();
});
```

Comment: I already have it in my provider.

Comment: Could you share the whole test file here?

Comment: And the error you are getting

Comment: my code is a bit large. what I want is the above mention SO link- , the stub is created by createSpyObj but I want to do the same thing using my custom object.because  i want to return the values.

Comment: Then injector should do that, simply use spyOnProperty on its result.

Comment: in test inject and provide do same thing right?

Comment: yep - I've updated my answer with an example.